Smooth Brush is not working properly. It shows a line and smooths that region when I move it
while Sculpting, I am having a problem with the smooth brush. It was working perfectly earlier, but I think I pressed a key and now it creates a line instead of a round circle cursor. And when I drag it now, the cursor stays there and the line scales. I want it back the normal way like when I move it on a surface it smooths the surface.

This red line is formed when I try to drag the smooth brush.

I got it!
I pressed Shift+S in sculpt mode by mistake which made my smooth brush enabled with Stabilize Strokes. I turned it off by pressing Shift+S again and now my smooth brush works fine. You can also disable this feature from the Stroke method menu.

with blender, if you sneeze or twitch you may lose a day's work!  ;)

I think you just need to change the Stroke Method.

It is a line because the Line method is selected.
You can change it to dots or airbrush.
Hope this helps :)

No I have the space method selected and for all other brushes its also space stroke method But all brushes other than smooth work fine.
